# OpenMP parallel do read write race condition?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am a little bit confused about the race conditions that can occur in OpenMP

Specifically, I have two arrays `A` and `B` that contains data, and I wish to use the data in one, compute something, and store it to other.

my fortran code would look like this

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(tmp,data)
DO i = 1, 10000
   tmp = A(i) !!Extract A(i)
   data = Do_Stuff(tmp) !!Compute
   B(i)=data !!Store
END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

are there any lurking race conditions here?

I'm asking because in pages 11-12 in the introduction i'm [reading](http://www.openmp.org/presentations/miguel/F95_OpenMPv1_v2.pdf) the code bellow has this problem, even though the index `i` is different for all iterations.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
do i = 1, 1000
    B(i) = 10 * i
    A(i) = A(i) + B(i)
end do 
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Comment: Where exactly did you find that claim?

Comment: If you mean pages 11-12 the I believe that claim is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a race condition in your first example.

The variable `data` is not explicitly given a data sharing attribute and doesn't have a predetermined attribute, consequently in a parallel construct it is shared.  Multiple threads will read and write to it.

There is no such condition in your second example.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cited article claims there is some problem with the second example, but that is probably some misunderstanding by the author.

Comment: I agree.       xyzzy xyzzy

Comment: I had a typo in my privade declaration: psi, should be data. Are both construcs safe now?

Comment: Perhaps.  The answer depends on the declaration of, and defined operations accessible for, A, B, data and tmp.  I can't see them.