# Incorrect claim about (in)correct use of OMP DO-construct in "official" Fortran OMP tutorial?

Tags: openmp

This [tutorial](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/F95_OpenMPv1_v2.pdf) about parallel programming using OpenMP in Fortran, found on
the OpenMP website, contains the following example (see pages 11-12):

```
real(8) :: A(1000), B(1000)

do i = 1, 1000
    B(i) = 10 * i
    A(i) = A(i) + B(i)
enddo
```

The text surrounding this example reads:

> Since each thread is executing part of the iterations of the do-loop
> and the updates of the modifications made to the variables are not
> ensured until the end of the work-sharing construct, the following
> example will not work correctly using the !$OMP DO/!$OMP END DO
> directive-pair for its parallelization because the correct value of
> the matrix B is not ensured until the end of the work-sharing
> construct !$OMP END DO.

My question is two-fold:

- Why would this example not work correctly using the OpenMP
  DO-construct? The thread that reads B(i) is also the only thread that
  writes it.
- What does "work correctly" mean for this example? Are arrays always
  zero-initialized automatically in Fortran?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530753/openmp-parallel-do-read-write-race-condition) suggests that, in fact, the example does work correctly
using OpenMP, and the tutorial is incorrect. Yet, the tutorial is linked from
the official OpenMP website.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  You're absolutely right that the tutorial is wrongly making that statement.  In fact, the code you're pointing is perfectly legal parallel code and one of the posterchild codes for doing parallelization.  I will talk to the OpenMP webteam to see what the ARB should be doing with that tutorial.

Comment: That's a 2002 tutorial. There are examples on the OMP website that are more with the times.